# change img src on select box selection

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a form that populates input fields using jQuery and AJAX. I can not get the `img` URL to change in the `src` when I select the option from the dynamically populated dropdown.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url     : 'get_driver_data2.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $('#ContactTrucks').serialize(),
            success: function( data ) {
                   for(var id in data) {        
                          $(id).val( data[id] );
                   }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
$id_selected = $_POST['id']; // Selected  Id
$query  = "SELECT * from admin_dispatch_records where id = '$id_selected' AND     driver LIKE '%$username%'";
$result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $eta = $row['eta'];
    $time = $row['dispatch_time'];
    $date = $row['dispatch_date'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $phone = $row['phone'];
    $vehicleyear = $row['vehicleyear'];
    $color = $row['color'];
    $make = $row['make'];
    $model = $row['model'];
    $vin = $row['vin'];
    $plate = $row['plate'];
    $mileage = $row['mileage'];
    $pickup = $row['pickup'];
    $dropoff = $row['dropoff'];
    $price = $row['price'];
    $invoice = $row['invoice'];
    $cash = $row['cash'];
    $credit = $row['credit'];
    $check = $row['check'];
    $po = $row['po'];
    $billed = $row['billed'];
    $need_to_bill = $row['need_to_bill'];
    $getphoto = $row['image_path'];
}

$arr = array( 'input#eta' => $eta, 'input#dispatch_time' => $time, 'input#dispatch_date' => $date, 'input#name' => $name, 'input#phone' => $phone, 'input#vehicleyear' => $vehicleyear, 'input#color' => $color, 'input#make' => $make, 'input#model' => $model, 'input#vin' => $vin, 'input#plate' => $plate, 'input#mileage' => $mileage, 'textarea#pickup' => $pickup, 'textarea#dropoff' => $dropoff, 'input#price' => $price, 'input#invoice' => $invoice, 'input#cash' => $cash, 'input#credit' => $credit, 'input#check' => $check, 'input#po' => $po, 'input#billed' => $billed, 'input#need_to_bill' => $need_to_bill, 'image#image_path' => $getphoto);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

A bit of the HTML:

```
<td>
<img id="image_path" src="????" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<p><strong>
<input type="submit" value="Complete Dispatch">
</strong></p>
```

How do I populate the `src` with the database value from the AJAX call when I change the select box? All other data is populated and the string is returned correctly. I have tested that by placing an input box and including `input#image_path => $getphoto`. Is the syntax for an `img` tag different from `input` or `textarea`? I have tried including the PHP inline and assigning the `src` to `$getphoto` with no luck. I was look to make a hidden input field with the AJAX passed data and then taking that data and making it a var but can not figure that out either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JavaScript doesn't set the `src` attribute of your `<img>`.

After your `for` loop, you can pull the data out of the array like this:

```
$("#image_path").attr("src", data['image#image_path']);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to use the hidden `<input>` approach, that would look something like:

HTML:

```
<td>
<input type="hidden" id="image_path" value="default.png" />
<img id="photo" src="default.png" />
</td>
```

PHP:

```
$arr = array('input#eta' => $eta,
             ...
             'input#image_path' => $getphoto);
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#id").change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url     : 'get_driver_data2.php',
            type    : 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data    : $('#ContactTrucks').serialize(),
            success : function(data) {
                          for(var id in data) {        
                              $(id).val(data[id]);
                          }
                          $("#photo").attr("src", $("#image_path").val());
                      }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: that works great using the hidden field changes when I change the select filed. is there a way to do that without having a hidden field

Comment: yes added $("#image_path").attr("src", data['image#image_path']); and kept .... 'image#image_path' => $getphoto and it works as well i like the first option as it does not show a broken link thanks for the quick response you rock

Comment: I also set the the column like this <img id="image_path" />

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
if (id=="image_path") $(id).attr("src", data[id] );
else $(id).val( data[id] );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attr()` to change the `src` like this:

```
$(id).attr("src", data[id]);   // chnage the source of the img tag
```

In this case, you can use a conditional statement in your `for` loop like this:

```
if(id=="image_path"){
   $(id).attr("src", data[id]);
}else{
   $(id).val(data[id]);
}
```